# What's the difference between the first method that runs Task.Run and the one which doesn't run Task.Run?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, task

The listenForClients1 method doesn't block the main thread but the listenForClients2 does. Why is there a difference here? Both tasks seems to be executing but the second doesn't begin working on a new thread.

I want the task to run on a different thread but I'm very confused to why I need to call the Task.Run and what that specific static method does differently that makes the task perform on a different thread?

```
            if(temp.Name == "buttonStart" && int.TryParse(textBoxPort.Text, out port)) //Startar servern...
            {
                #region Btn appearance:

                temp.Enabled = false;
                buttonStop.Enabled = true;
                buttonStart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(108, 156, 67);
                buttonStop.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(212, 101, 78);

                #endregion

                listeningTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = listeningTokenSource.Token;

                listenForClients1(token);

                Invoke(() => { richTextBoxLog.Text += "Testing"; });
            }
            else if(temp.Name == "buttonStop") //Stoppar servern...
            {
                #region Btn appearance:

                temp.Enabled = false;
                buttonStart.Enabled = true;
                buttonStart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(145, 207, 91);
                buttonStop.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(156, 76, 59);

                #endregion

                listeningTokenSource.Cancel(); //Stoppar processen.
            }
        }

        private async Task listenForClients1(CancellationToken token)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Invoke(() => { richTextBoxLog.Text += "b"; });
                }
                Invoke(() => { richTextBoxLog.Text += "Done"; });
            });
        }

        private async Task listenForClients2(CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Invoke(() => { richTextBoxLog.Text += "b"; });
            }
            Invoke(() => { richTextBoxLog.Text += "Done"; });
        }
```

Thank you for any answers! Best regards, Lukas.

I tried different methods and expected them both to not block the main thread.

Comment: Where/how do you call `listenForClients2`?

Answer (score 2):

The first one hands off the code to a threadpool thread and will not block. The second function has no handling whatsoever for asynchonicity, so it will block. `Invoke` was not necessary in the second function, and it's unclear why you needed it.

**But neither of these options are correct.** What you *should* do is use `await Task.Delay` instead, rather than making a blocking `Thread.Sleep` call.

You also need to call the function using `await`, otherwise dragons may jump out your screen.

```cs
private async Task listenForClients3(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
            richTextBoxLog.Text += "b";
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { //
    }
    richTextBoxLog.Text += "Done";
}
```

```cs
await listenForClients3(someToken);
```

Note that there is a slight difference in logic here: because we passed the token to `Task.Delay` we may get cancelled in the middle of it, whereas the original code will not break out until the end of the timer. To avoid that behaviour you can do `await Task.Delay(1000);`

Comment: @Gottegubben Rather than thanking, you can upvote and/or accept the answer (by clicking the check mark)